# How to reset sorcedata of ExcelPivotTable in EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I want to reset sorcedata of ExcelPivotTable,but EPPLus only provide ExcelPivotTable.PivotTables.Add(). How to reset sorcedata?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please tell us, what you have already tried

Comment: I has creat a ExcelPivotTable, i want to dynamic reset the sorcedata of ExcelPivotTable,but i don't know how to do.

Comment: This will end in a long Cmment-Battle if you dont post some code and tell us based on your code where you're stuck at

Comment: I has create an Excel PivotTable Template,but has no data. Now I used Epplus set some data,but PivotTable can not show the data.I wanted to add a new sheet to display and set filed like the old one.

Comment: ExcelWorksheet wsPivot = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PivotSimple");
ExcelPivotTable pivotTable1 = wsPivot.PivotTables.Add(wsPivot.Cells["A1"], objSrcRange, "PerEmploee");

foreach (ExcelPivotTableField objPF in objPT.RowFields) {
    string tempName = objPF.Name;
        ExcelPivotTableField tempField = pivotTable1.Fields.First(x => x.Name == tempName);
        pivotTable1.RowFields.Add(tempField);
}

Comment: But the new sheet style is not the same as the old one. So i want to know how to dynamic reset the sorcedata of ExcelPivotTable.